# Unable to connect to Postgres DB by specifying the schema name

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I am using below versions of DB and jdbc driver ::

1. Postgres DB , Version :: 14.1.1
2. postgresSql , Version :: 42.2.10
3. spark Sql , Version :: 3.4.1

I am trying to connect to DB schema by following way ::

```
sparkSession.read().format("jdbc").option("url",configuredProperties.
                        getProperty("FinanceCoreDbUrl")).
                option("user", configuredProperties.getProperty("FinanceCoreDbUser")).
                option("password", configuredProperties.getProperty("FinanceCoreDbPassword")).
                option("ssl", configuredProperties.getProperty("financeDbSsl")).
                option("sslmode", "verify-full").
                option("schema", configuredProperties.getProperty("FinanceCoreDbSchema")).
                option("sslrootcert", configuredProperties.getProperty("financeDbSslRootCert")).
                option("sslcert", configuredProperties.getProperty("financeDbSslCertPath")).option("sslkey",
                        configuredProperties.getProperty("financeDbSslKey"));
```

I have used 1.search_path 2. searchpath 2. schema 3. currentschema but nothing is working. It always connect to public schema.

Comment: 1) You don't connect to a `schema` you connect to a `database`. 2) In the JDBC driver there is `currentSchema` per [Initialization](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/), but it just sets the `search_path`. 3) Regardless of the `search_path` you can access any object in a schema you have privileges on if you schema qualify the name.